Infinite query processing in Prolog
I have got my homework from Prolog to make an 1 dimensional minesweeper board that contains only two rows .
I wrote predicate:
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

symbol(0, o). 
symbol(1, x).

relate_numbers_to_mines([],[]).
relate_numbers_to_mines([_],[]).
relate_numbers_to_mines([],[_]).
relate_numbers_to_mines([],[_,_]).
relate_numbers_to_mines([N|Nums],[M1,M2,M3|Mines]) :- 
    N in 0..3, [M1,M2,M3] ins 0..1, N #= M1 + M2 + M3,
    relate_numbers_to_mines(Nums,[M2,M3|Mines]).

trnsmute([],[]).
trnsmute([M1|Mines], [M2|BMines]) :- 
    symbol(M1, M2), 
    trnsmute(Mines, BMines).

mines(Nums, Symbols) :-
    length(Nums, Length),
    LengthPlusTwo is Length + 2,
    length(Mines, LengthPlusTwo), 
    Mines = [0|AMines], append(BMines, [0], AMines), 
    BMines ins 0..1,
    relate_numbers_to_mines(Nums, Mines),
    trnsmute(BMines, Symbols),
    label(BMines).



and for the query
 ?- mines(L, [o, x, o, x, o, o, x, o]).
L = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

It goes infinite loading . How can I fix it ?

Run e.g.: mines(L, [o, x, o, x, o, o, x, o]), trace. to see the backtracking. Looks like label should be called before trnsmute. Also, why use clpfd here, what's the benefit, when the downside is e.g. complexity of debugging?
